# how to correct mislabeled data in training, validation and test set

Tags: deep-learning, training, supervised-learning

In an image classification task, I know there are mislabeled data. should I remove/correct them in all training / validation / test set ?

I saw this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.14749.pdf but I am not sure if I understood the result correctly - does adding mislabel improve the performance ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say yes : if you have mislabeled data in train, the model won't learn correctly, and if you have them in test/val, your test results won't represent the actual model results.

Since that's directly the label, that's ok to correct/remove them, since you'd never have the label in real new cases. Moreover, if you encounter the same problem with a variable, it's more difficult to deal with, since the variable may also have misvalues in the future application of your model.

Answer (score 2):

I’m the lead author of that paper :)

Mislabeled data *can* detrimentally effect the performance of ML models. **The primary takeaway of that paper is that you need to use accurately labeled test sets when benchmarking. You also should train your models on accurately labeled data**.

The easiest (one-line-of-code) way to find mislabeled data is via the [cleanlab](https://docs.cleanlab.ai) data-centric AI python package: https://github.com/cleanlab/cleanlab which works for **any dataset you can train a classifier on** for most data formats, ML and deep learning frameworks, and data modalities, e.g. image, text, tabular, and audio data.

### Find label issues in 1 line of code

```py
from cleanlab.classification import CleanLearning
from cleanlab.filter import find_label_issues

# Option 1 - works with sklearn-compatible models - just input the data and labels ツ
label_issues_info = CleanLearning(clf=sklearn_compatible_model).find_label_issues(data, labels)

# Option 2 - works with ANY ML model - just input the model's predicted probabilities
ordered_label_issues = find_label_issues(
    labels=labels,
    pred_probs=pred_probs,  # out-of-sample predicted probabilities from any model
    return_indices_ranked_by='self_confidence',
)
```

### Train a model as if the dataset did not have errors -- 3 lines of code

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from cleanlab.classification import CleanLearning

cl = CleanLearning(clf=LogisticRegression())  # any sklearn-compatible classifier
cl.fit(train_data, labels)

# Estimate the predictions you would have gotten if you trained without mislabeled data.
predictions = cl.predict(test_data)
```

Documentation and runnable tutorials for cleanlab: https://docs.cleanlab.ai/

### The above approaches find issues. To correct label issues in your dataset...

The above approaches, just find issues and train without them. To correct the labels or train a model on a corrected dataset (that still includes all the errors, but now corrected with the right label), there is a no-code tool for that called [Cleanlab Studio](https://cleanlab.ai/studio) (https://cleanlab.ai/studio) for which I am also an author.